# Activate the activator class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am using eclipse 3.6. I created one sample plugin application. It is neither a eclipse rcp nor workbench. Now when I run the eclipse I want that plugin also to be loaded. But I dont want to use IStartUp. Because what I have found out is
IStartup will be called after the workbench is loaded. I want to refresh some menu. So Is there any way to activate my plugin while the eclipse loaded?
I tried to use Bundle Activation policy. But that is also not activating my Activator class. I just put one System.out. println("Inside start()"). So that is not called. Now can I make it activate my activator?

**EDIT:**

what my exact requirement is, I have created one workbench application.It is not eclipse rcp application. Now I want to remove  the following menu and menu items from the eclipse before the eclipe is loaded.
1. File Menu 
2.) Search Menu 
3.)Run Menu 
4.)Help->search,Dynamic Help,Key assist,Tips and trick,Report Bug,Cheat Sheet.

These menus are inbuilt menu of eclipse. So that is the reason I have to do in this way.

So I already implemented by using startup extension point. But the early startup is called after the eclipse is started.So I need to do some refreshment on the workbench.Then only the menu item will get removed.So I thought I need startup extension point will not satisfy my requirement as it doesnot refresh the workbench.I need to activate the my plugin and refresh the workbench before it is loaded.

Thanks
Bhanu

Comment: You can resolve the problem same as:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43384921/5147033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the needed [start level](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/) for your plugin using touch point instruction.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. It is working fine.But one problem iam facing. I got the some exception. Below are the exceptions.  Exception is related to Workbech could be not created.org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.

Comment: This means that your plug-in starts before the workbench is created. You have to use UIJob or WorkbenchJob so your code will be executed when workbench is ready.

Comment: How do you I do that? could you please give some example?

Comment: In your plugin's start method: `Job j = new WorkbenchJob("") { public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) { // XXX: run your code; return Status.OK_STATUS; } }; j.schedule();`

Answer (score 1):

You are just a plugin that expects to run in the Eclipse IDE?

Then the answer is, you cannot do what you want.

If you start before the workbench has finished initializing, most of the services that could be used won't work:  The workbench itself, menu service, command service, etc.

For most plugins in eclipse, the **plugin.xml** should be used to add menus, views, editors, etc to eclipse.  When necessary, the framework will instantiate them.

`org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` is available and as you mentioned it will be called after the workbench has been initialized, but before any windows have been shown.  It's not to be used lightly, and not by plugins contributing to the UI as it allows all extension from that plugin to be loaded.

**EDIT:**

If you are an **RCP app**, you control the main menu.  As an RCP app, you have access to the `ActionBarAdvisor`, `WorkbenchAdvisor`, `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`, which all have lifecycle methods.

If you are an an **eclipse plugin**, you can add to the main menu ... you cannot easily remove from the main menu.  This is by design.  Start levels and *org.eclipse.ui.startup* are 2 mechanisms that **won't** do what you want.

**You still need to answer these questions:**
There might still be a way.  The crux of your problem is: "I want to refresh some menu"

1. What kind of menu (popup, main menu,
   compound list of menu items in a
   menu, etc)?
2. Where is the menu contribution coming from?
3. Which specific menu item is it?

Please edit your question (do not comment) and include the information from the above 3 questions, please.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the information. what my exact requirement is, I want to remove some menus from the main menu of the eclipse before the eclipe is  loaded. So I already implemented  by using startup extension point. But the early startup is called after the eclipse is started.So I need to do some refreshment on the workbench.Then only the menu item will get removed.So I thought I need startup extension point will not satisfy my requirement as it doesnot refresh the workbench.I need to activate the my plugin and refresh the workbench before it is loaded.

Comment: For that as Spektom suggested, I had to use the start level of my plugin. But when I used the startlevel of my plugin, this is called before the any UI framework is loaded. Due to this reason, I got the exception, Workbench not create yet. This is the problem I am facing.Now I need to refresh my menu removal code before the eclipse is loaded.