# How to activate a plugin when Eclipse loads?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to activate my plugin once Eclipse starts? I have extended a JavaCompletionProposalComputer to compute a list a completions to be shown when CTRL+SPACE has been pressed. And in the purpose of my work I needed to listen to any change in the workspace; so, I implemented an IResourceChangeListener class. However, the Listener never starts if the user decides not to use content assist.

To Solve the problem, I was about to remove the lazy parameter in Bundle-ActivationPolicy but I read somewhere that it is a bad idea. Another, way was to use IStartup from the package org.eclipse.ui.startup; however, the user might disable the earlyStartup feature in the system preferences.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem? Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: What is the purpose of having the listener registered if user doesn't use content assist? If your plugin provides also some other functionality then try to find appropriate extension point that would trigger your code.

Comment: @vanaprogeja yes it does seem pointless but the plugin does provide other functionalities that are not GUI based. So there are no extension that I can think of that would trigger my plugin from the very start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what workspace save participants are for.  See the section on "Processing resource deltas between activations" at http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_saving.htm?cp=2_0_11_3.

Answer (score 2):

> To Solve the problem, I was about to remove the lazy parameter in Bundle-ActivationPolicy but I read somewhere that it is a bad idea.

Removing `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` means your plugin won't be activated automatically at all.

> Another, way was to use IStartup from the package org.eclipse.ui.startup; however, the user might disable the earlyStartup feature in the system preferences.

This is the only correct way to do this. If the user disables early startup, that's his prerogative. So you should still provide some way to activate your plugin in this case.

Comment: I would leave it to the user but in the context of my work it is not a good idea. In addition, if I register the listener using the earlyStartup I have no idea how I would do to unregister the listener.

Comment: If you find a way to get your plugin to activate on startup without letting the user disable it, it should likely be reported to Eclipse as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to point out that it is generally considerered bad practice to force a plugin to always start when Eclipse starts. This will make your plugin go active even if you want to use Eclipse for something completly unrelated.

I remember that Aptanas thought their Ruby plugins were so important they had to integrate themselves all over the place and automatically connect to a bunch of webpages whenever Eclipse started. It was horrible, I had to delete the Eclipse installation to get rid of it...

Anyway, with that said;

Check out [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722963/plugin-eclipse-auto-start-in-product), it seems to be the same as your problem